# request help with the evaluation of a double integral

Tags: calculus

I am having trouble understanding how to go about evaluating the following integral

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{0}^{u} \sqrt{y+\tan^{2}(x)} \,dx\,dy,$$ where $0 < u < \frac{\pi}{2}$.

I am confused about the limit of integration of the inner integral with u varying between $0$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My best guess is that $u$ is a constant, so you're integration over a rectangle.  If you switch the order of integration, things work out pretty easily:

$$\int_0^u \int_0^1 \sqrt{y+\tan^2 x} \;dy \; dx = \int_0^u \left.\frac{2}{3}\left(y+\tan^2 x\right)^{3/2} \right|_0^1 \; dx  $$

$$= \int_0^u \frac{2}{3}\left((1+\tan^2x)^{3/2} - (\tan^2 x)^{3/2}\right) \; dx$$

$$= \frac{2}{3}\int_0^u \sec^3 x - \tan^3x \; dx.$$

Did I say "easily"?  Well, for some definition of "easily".  These are standard integrals, so grind them out and plug in $u$ and $0$.

Comment: thank you for the clarification.  I at first was not sure if i can treat the u as a constant.  But from the last line, after evaluating from 0 to u, i calulate the last integral using 0 and $\pi/2$, is that correct.  Or do I interpret it as an improper integral where u goes to 0 in one direction, and $\pi/2$ in the other direction.  Thanks

Comment: I think you just treat $u$ as a constant and plug it in.  Unless there's more to the problem which you're not sharing...?

Comment: the problem only states that u varies between 0 and $\pi/2$.  Again, thank you for the help.  I really appreciate it.  :)